# Geowebcache automatic seed is not working

Tags: geoserver, geowebcache

I created new geowebcache task via form as following:

[image]

But my task list is empty:

[image]

I want to create tiles automatically. How can I do this?

**UPDATE:**

I noticed that geoserver seed is seeding geoserver default sample data. For example I seed **topp:tasmania_state** that source is file. But I am creating postgresql publish from database, this is not working. EPSG is 4326. But gwc demo page is creating tiles.

Comment: check the logs for hints: tail -f /var/log/tomcat7/catalina.out . Supplement your question with the logfile

Comment: First thing to test is that your grid set really works. You can check it with the automated demos from /gwc/demo url. I have also found that "generate missing tiles" does not work always, like it thinks that everything is done already. Reseed feels more reliable. Practical advice: seed with a few more threads and use the coordinate boxes for cutting the task to reasonable pieces. If the only thread dies you do not know where it stopped. Aim is to run batches which will complete in couple of hours. You can automate seeding in small batches by making a script that runs REST reseed commands.